# How to connect all components of a DiGraph in NetworkX

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have a directed graph (G), which is made of 65 strongly connected components and 8 weakly connected components. I am aware I can add non-existent edges to connect the entire graph using k-edge-augmentation, but this is only possible with an undirected graph.

Is there any way, within NetworkX, or otherwise to connect the DiGraph to produce one strongly connected component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming here in future, one idea I had which I'm probably going to go with is to create both a directed and undirected graph from your data, perform k-edge-augmentation on the undirected graph, and using the edges this returns, add a biconnected component between them in the directed graph.